# NAS Rebuild - Raid 5, 6 or 10 w/12TB Drives in QNAP TS-869L

Tags: hard-drive, raid, nas

Since I am not using this for business, are there any clear reasons to go with Raid10 over Raid5/6 with these extremely [large 12TB Drives][1].  My workload is Read Intensive (comparatively) so I expect a similar speeds with any raid level.

Current:
2TBx8 RAID5

Option1: Most Capacity, Fastest
12TBx4 RAID5

Option2: Fast Rebuild
12TBx4 RAID10

Option3: 2nd Most Capacity After 4 drives.
12TBx4 RAID6

I've had 2TB Drives go bad and it took 24 hours to rebuild Raid5 w/8 disks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data Loss Risk is a calculable constant, does not matter if it's for personal or business use.

If the important data is backed up, and the other data can be lost with acceptable impact, raid5 would be fine, raid 6 would be **best** clearly shown below.

[RAID Reliability Calculator results](http://wintelguy.com/raidmttdl.pl)

**Probability of data loss over time**

```
Raid 10, 2TB Drives, 5 Years - 0.00039
Raid 10, 12TB Drives, 5 Years - 0.0017
Raid 5, 2TB Drives, 5 Years - 0.0027
Raid 5, 12TB Drives, 5 Years - 0.0118
Raid 6, 2TB Drives, 5 Years - 0.000001
Raid 6, 12TB Drives, 5 Years - 0.00001
```

Above differences with these values (only changing highlighted number)
[image: Guesstimate]

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using RAID5 as the likelyhood of failure while the disks is rebuilding is very high, and then bye-bye data.

RAID10 is probably the best way of doing things, and the safest if you take into account possible problems with the NAS "raid controller".

RAID6 will provide a similar amount of storage, with slightly higher redundancy (any 2 disks can fail, but, on the other chance, a much greater chances of failure during a rebuild) at the penalty of much more complex and slower writes.

Comment: "are there any clear reasons"  Looking for more data like below to make an informed decision.